# Applying text decoration on hover

Tags: html, css

So, I am creating a simple site and can't figure out a solution for the life of me. I want to apply text decoration to some text, here is how it's laid out.

It essentially goes like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="listing">
            <p id="title">Dev</p>
            <p id="location">New York City</p>
            <p id="salary">$30/hr</p>
            <p id="desc">Description</p>
            <p id="tag">Remote</p>
        </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

So basically I want to apply text decoration to the #title ID when you hover over the .wrapper class. I only know the way to apply it while hovering over the #title, which is fine if it's not possible, but I would like to know if there is a way. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper:hover #title {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="listing">
            <p id="title">Dev</p>
            <p id="location">New York City</p>
            <p id="salary">$30/hr</p>
            <p id="desc">Description</p>
            <p id="tag">Remote</p>
        </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper:hover #title {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

This is how you target the title. I'd suggest you remove the text decoration from the parent link tag then style the children tag as you want.

Comment: @truckerwes24 please mark as answer the post that helped you

Comment: I had to wait to do so. just made this account since I lost my other.